# How to open a new port in apache

Tags: apache, centos

I want to open a new port in apache so that i can accept http requests on the port with http://ip:port

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Binding to Addresses and Ports](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html):

> For example, to make the server accept connections on both port 80 and
>   port 8000, on all interfaces, use:
>
> ```
> Listen 80
> Listen 8000
> ```
>
> To make the server accept connections on port 80 for one interface,
>   and port 8000 on another, use
>
> ```
> Listen 192.0.2.1:80
> Listen 192.0.2.5:8000
> ```
>
> IPv6 addresses must be enclosed in square brackets, as in the
>   following example:
>
> ```
> Listen [2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea]:80
> ```